# Hide HTTP Destination with a Raspbery Pi

Tags: networking, proxy, http, raspberry-pi

I wanna realize some kind of WebServer or Proxy on my Raspberry Pi that hides the real http requests from any firewall. Following scenario:

> computer@school --Request--> myRPi --Request--> destination 
>   Response: 
>   computer@school <--Result-- myRPi <--Result-- destination

But with restricted vision for computer@school:

> computer@school --> myRPi
>   Response: computer@school <-- myRPi

Is there a way to realize that without the use of SSH or VPN-Service ?

Comment: Re the proxy on the pi, I thought about, perhaps an HTTPS Proxy, but then if you HTTP to it then maybe it wouldn't encrypt and thus wouldn't hide the proxy request.  People can get so inclined to ssh that it cripples the mind somewhat and people tend not to look for other solutions.. it's an interesting question. I like "without ssh" questions!

Comment: I have an idea, you can use stunnel

Comment: Hmm interesting :D I'm quite new to the whole networking/webserver/proxy thing ... So how do you think this could work? I set up the stunnel on my RPi on a specific port and have to install stunnel on my Client as well to establish a connection between server and client?  Does the stunnel client (on windows) need any specific permissions or what does it change within the system?

Comment: For Windows, there's a windows port of stunnel, and there's an stunnel that runs in cygwin..   There may be an issue installing it where it asks about a certificate.

Comment: As for your question about permissions, asking such a question isn't the right approach. You should try and install it, see what errors you get.

Comment: see my answer, though it doesn't cover a)setting up the proxy, even putting aside any encryption  b)any issues installing stunnel e.g. if it requires a certificate.

Comment: perfect scenario would be some kind of chrome extension taking over the part of the stunnel client server :D But i think that might be pretty hard to find ;) Especially when opening special ports is not an option

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it for a while but there is a program called stunnel.

It has a configuration file, where you specify an input port(to accept a connection on) and an output port(to connect to).

It has a client mode, and a server mode.

The openssl server in client mode (A) accepts the connection from the client program e.g. web browser making the proxy request, and it will encrypt it with ssl, and can sit on your school computer.

The openssl server in server mode (B) will sit where the raspberry pi is, which is where the proxy server is.  It will accept the connection from the openssl server on the school computer, and it will then connect to the proxy where it sits , which is on the pi.

So, instead of..

school        to  pi http proxy  to destination

you'd have

school comp web client making http proxy request TO school comp openssl server, TO pi comp openssl server TO pi comp http proxy to dest comp http server.

and that'd be encrypted.

As for configuring stunnel, it has been a while but the main part is 3 lines in the configuration file e.g.

This would be if it was for securing POP and you wanted both SSL client and SSL server.  (Some uses of stunnel require just an openssl client e.g. your client program doesn't support ssl and needs to connect to a server that does), and some stunnel uses require just a server e.g. your server program doesn't support ssl and you want it to.   For your usage, you need both client mode openssl server and server mode openssl server

Excuse the example(it being using pop3 and pop3 ports) but it's just to illustrate the principle.

This file is called stunnel.conf or something like that

```
; Example SSL server mode services

;[pop3s]
;client = no  <-- default
;accept  = 995
;connect = 110

; Example SSL client mode services

;[gmail-pop3]
;client = yes
;accept = 127.0.0.1:110
;connect = pop.gmail.com:995
```

The principle can be applied for an http proxy.

Comment: wow.... that sounds amazing already! Thats huge! Really sounds like it could really work. I'm quite sure, that I can find some stunnel guides around. Only thing is, that I don't have administrative permissions on the schoolcomp, that's why installing a client server might be impossible... Also I think that the firewall is blocking the stunnel port by default... But I'll take a deep look at it. So, thank you very much in advance for your time and effort :)

Comment: @cosi well, it can benefit others too. But in your case, if you lack admin priv.. then i'm not sure how you'd do it. ssh can do it without admin priv.

Comment: yeah your idea and guide surely helps a guy that has the same thoughts as mine :D sadly the ssh port on the schoolcomp is also locked, thats why I'm not able to connect to my ssh via putty :(

Comment: @cosi with the ssh server on your raspberry pi, put your ssh server on port 80

Comment: will try that! really good idea actually :D i'm currently running on a proxy server which I'm able to connect from school to any website... Is there any way for me to see what connection type this proxy is using? (it's a simple google chrome extension --> paid service)

Comment: @cosi  there isn't really a technical term "connection type" but regarding konwing the details of how the connection is done e.g. whether it's encrypted or not, I suppose perhaps not but perhaps it could be if it's an extension. What is the name of the Chrome extension?  You could use Wireshark to inspect the connection and see everything e.g. whether it's encrypted or not. You'd see tons of stuff and you'd have to add filters like ip.dst==4.5.6.7(or something like that) where 4.5.6.7 is your proxy.

Comment: The extension is called easy proxy. It's free mode allows to use the proxy for connections to facebook only, but that could be enough. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-proxy/egnccllcfmpcmeccejlbbnmobnaglbka Not sure how good I am with wireshark, but will give it a try later on... Thanks really much already... !